# Android Studio 2.0+ crashes on OS X

Tags: android-studio-2.0, android-studio-2.1

i haven't been able to run any version of Android Studio 2.x. it crashes seemingly randomly with this same exception after < 1min of simply navigating through files in a project:

```
Exception Name: JavaNativeException
Description: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.lwawt.macosx.CAccessibility.getAccessibleIndexInParent(CAccessibility.java:287)

User Info: (null)

0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff94a9e4f2 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff88d51f7e objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff94a9e439 -[NSException raise] + 9
3   JavaNativeFoundation                0x000000011be9251f JNFCallStaticIntMethod + 236
4   libawt_lwawt.dylib                  0x000000011d7c8deb +[JavaComponentAccessibility createWithAccessible:withEnv:withView:] + 76
5   libawt_lwawt.dylib                  0x000000011d7c930b -[JavaComponentAccessibility accessibilityFocusedUIElement] + 194
6   libawt_lwawt.dylib                  0x000000011d79e4f6 -[AWTView accessibilityFocusedUIElement] + 156
7   AppKit                              0x00007fff98c44d37 -[NSWindow(NSWindowAccessibility) accessibilityFocusedUIElement] + 118
8   libawt_lwawt.dylib                  0x000000011d7c9069 +[JavaComponentAccessibility postFocusChanged:] + 96
9   Foundation                          0x00007fff9427af5e __NSThreadPerformPerform + 279
10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff94a33881 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
11  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff94a12fbc __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
12  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff94a124df __CFRunLoopRun + 927
13  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff94a11ed8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
14  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff963fe935 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
15  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff963fe76f ReceiveNextEventCommon + 432
16  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff963fe5af _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
17  AppKit                              0x00007fff98463efa _DPSNextEvent + 1067
18  AppKit                              0x00007fff9846332a -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 454
19  libosxapp.dylib                     0x000000011d8503aa -[NSApplicationAWT nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 124
20  AppKit                              0x00007fff98457e84 -[NSApplication run] + 682
21  libosxapp.dylib                     0x000000011d85014d +[NSApplicationAWT runAWTLoopWithApp:] + 156
22  libawt_lwawt.dylib                  0x000000011d7dd4b3 -[AWTStarter starter:] + 905
23  Foundation                          0x00007fff9427af5e __NSThreadPerformPerform + 279
24  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff94a33881 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
25  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff94a12fbc __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
26  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff94a124df __CFRunLoopRun + 927
27  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff94a11ed8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
28  studio                              0x00000001000012f3 main + 357
29  studio                              0x000000010000116c start + 52
30  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
```

i'm running OS X 10.11.4 with Java version 1.8.0_92.

i'd seen some other references to this problem in the context of doing drag & drop operations, but the accepted solution of upgrading the JDK version doesn't seem to have resolved my issue.

FWIW i'm able to run Studio 1.5 without encountering this issue.

Comment: sounds like you need to file a bug report.

Comment: Same here. I got this since updating to the public beta of MacOS Sierra.

Comment: *UPDATE* - i haven't had a crash reoccurrence since updating to Java 1.8.0_101. previously it would crash within a few minutes of casual usage (opening/closing files, navigating folders). been running for about 30min now without incident.

Comment: Android Studio 2.2 Preview 6 seems to fix this problem too -> https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/download/studio/canary/latest

Comment: Yep, Android 2.2 Beta versions don't have this problem anymore

Answer (score 0):

Answering a question of why it actually happens, but the [source](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/macosx/classes/sun/lwawt/macosx/CAccessibility.java#L290) has this:

```
    public static int getAccessibleIndexInParent(final Accessible a, final Component c) {
        if (a == null) return 0;

        return invokeAndWait(new Callable<Integer>() {
            public Integer call() throws Exception {
                final AccessibleContext ac = a.getAccessibleContext();
                if (ac == null) return null;
                return ac.getAccessibleIndexInParent();
            }
        }, c);
    }
```

As you can see, the `Callable` returns null in some situations, which is fine for an `Integer`, but you get a NPE as soon as it unboxes that to return `int`. They probably should be checking for null and returning 0.